# Regex Kotlin не работает

Tags: регулярные-выражения, kotlin

Мне надо узнать есть ли  в выражении математические знаки, я это пытаюсь сделать при помощи выражения, но получаю false.

```
val SINGS="[-\\+\\*\\/]".toRegex()
println(SINGS.matches("+4546+4-*5=4"))
```

Comment: [-\+\*\/] такое выражение

Comment: `[-+*\\\/]` будет реагировать на \ / - + *

Comment: [-+*] даже так не находит, прям беда.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/wZx6RB/1   Познаковый поиск, нельзя использовать `-` не первым символом, потому-что это Range Selector `a-z` символы \ и / обязательно надо эскейпить. На остальные знаки внутри `[]` ограничений вроде как нету.

Comment: println(SINGS.matches("+4546+4-5=4"))  возвращает false

Comment: [\-+*/] matches false а find находит первый из символов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`matches` сравнивает строку целиком

вам нужно использовать `containsMatchIn`

Comment: спасибо за помощь